# How can I make copy button on the form in C++ Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How can I make a copy button in visual studio 2019 using c++. Like in qt it's easy...

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionCopy_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->copy();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionPaste_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->paste();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionCut_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->cut();
}
```

But how to do it in visual studio 2019?

Comment: What ui framework are you using? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Ashiqul Islam Ayon Could you please tell us, which type of application do you want to use to achieve it? MFC? Winform? Win32?